# Why do I need to unwrap this variable?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
import SpriteKit

let NumOrientations: UInt32 = 4

enum Orientation: Int, Printable {
case Zero = 0, Ninety, OneEighty, TwoSeventy

var description: String {
    switch self {
        case .Zero:
            return "0"
        case .Ninety:
            return "90"
        case .OneEighty:
            return "180"
        case .TwoSeventy:
            return "270"
    }
}

static func random() -> Orientation {
    return Orientation(rawValue: Int(arc4random_uniform(NumOrientations)))!
}
}
```

I am new to swift, but I have a lot of programming experience. However, I've never encountered anything like the variable "wrapping" when dealing with unknowns in Swift.

I have the static function random, which returns an Orientation. There is NOTHING optional about the Orientation class. However, I have to use an exclamation point on the return statement in the random function.

Why is this? Excuse my complete lack of knowledge about swift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, obviously the initializer can fail. Let's assume:

```
Orientation(rawValue: 10)
```

This won't find a value in your enum, so what do you expect it to return? It will return `nil`. That means the return value must be an optional because `nil` can be returned.

This is explicitly mentioned in [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html), *Enumerations*, *Initializing from a Raw Value*:

> NOTE
>
> The raw value initializer is a failable initializer, because not every raw value will return an enumeration member. For more information, see Failable Initializers.

However, in this case (method `random`) you are sure that a `nil` won't be returned, so the best solution is to unwrap the optional before returning it from `random`.